# ASP.NET - How to bypass Update Command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to programmatically update a row in my GridView when user clicks Update. I have the ordinary Update working, but I need to have various validations in place. I already have a function which does this (checkDuplicate() in the code below) and I would like to simply reuse this function when Update is clicked. The problem is that updating requires an Update Command, and the Update Command does not have the validations in place. The checkDuplicate function works as expected, but so does the Update Command, which makes the checkDuplicate function worthless. So basically what I want to be able to do is bypass the Update Command so that I can just use the function I already have. Is this possible?

```
protected void update_Click(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    myDataSource.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [xyz] SET [s] = @s, [t] = @t, [c] = @c, [l] = @l, [p] = @p, [d] = @d, [k] = @k WHERE [Id] = @Id";

    lbStatusLabel2.Text= checkDuplicate(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text, GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text, GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Text, GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Text, GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Text, GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Text, GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Text, "45");
}
```

Comment: `checkDuplicate` is the validation function? What does it do and what doest it return when validation fails?

Comment: Yes. It returns an error message, if there is one. If I enter something incorrectly on update, I get the error message. So the checkDuplicate is working just fine. The problem is that the UpdateCommand is also executed, which renders the checkDuplicate irrelevant.

Comment: So you should execute `checkDuplicate` first and check if returns any error message. If it returns error message then don't run update command.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean? Because the issue is that apparently an update command is required. In other words, suppose I had a stupid if statement that said if (1==2) {don't do update command}, I would get an error because the update command is never reached, but an update command is required.

Comment: What error you get if you don't reach the update command?

Comment: "Updating is not supported by data source 'myDataSource' unless UpdateCommand is specified. "

Comment: Update: So I changed the UpdateCommand to something meaningless but valid, but I'm still getting an error message from checkDuplicate even when inputs are correct. I have no idea why. The exact same function works perfectly in another context. I thought maybe I had just made a typo somewhere, but that doesn't appear to be the case.